# Altering an Array from within Node JS net Socket

Tags: node.js, arrays, sockets

I am trying to update an array from within a server program, in order to record client data. However, whilst the positions array is updating okay, the board array (which obtains data from the positions array) never recognises these changes.  Thus the output (socket.write) never changes.  I feel I must be missing something obvious. This is a basic implementation of what I'm trying to do.  Thank you in advance.

````
const net = require('net');

const position = [" ", " ", " "];
const board = [position[0], "-", position[1], "-", position[2]];

const server = net.createServer(socket => {
    socket.on('data', data => {
        socket.write('Enter a value between 1 & 3 (inclusive)');
        const value = data.toString('utf-8');
        position[value-1] = 'X';
        board.forEach(item => {
            socket.write(item);
        })
    })

    socket.on('end', () => {
        console.log("Session ended");
    })
})

server.listen(5000);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two variables - `position` and `board` - are entirely independent (`board` does not hold references to `position`), so your modification to `position` is not carried over to `board`. This is because, in JavaScript, strings are pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference - any assignment of a string is a copy operation.

If you need to derive a value from another for sending, it's best to write a function that transforms your input to a desired output format, like so:

```js
toBoard(position) {
  return [position[0], "-", position[1], "-", position[2]];
}
```

and then

```js
        toBoard(position).forEach(item => {
            socket.write(item);
        })
```

Note, however, that your socket-related code has a serious bug: it treats `data` events as messages that come in individually. This is called *message* or *datagram* semantics, where a peer sends 1 message and the other peer receives the same message in its entirety. This is different from *stream* semantics, where a sequence of bytes is sent, and the same bytes come out on the other side, in the same order, but not necessarily sliced the same way.

With TCP, if the client does:

```js
socket.write('1');
socket.write('2');
socket.write('3');
```

The server may receive any of:

- one `data` event with '123'
- two `data` events with '1' and '23'
- two `data` events with '12' and '3'
- three separate `data` events with '1', '2' and '3'

You should look into protocols that preserve message boundaries, instead of using raw TCP. Here are some protocols you could use instead:

- UDP
- WebSocket
- ZeroMQ

If you decide to implement this on raw TCP yourself (which is error-prone), you'll need some logic to receive the stream progressively from the network, buffer and split the chunks accordingly into logical messages that you can process. A simple example of a built-in tool which does this is [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) - a module that converts a stream-oriented input (such as a TCP socket, or a process' standard input) into discrete `line` events.